# Dynamic Scrollbox Compatibility issue in Opera

Tags: html, css, scroll, opera

So, I have a dynamic scrollbox, generated using jquery, which loads values from an XML file, and updates as items are added or removed. I've gotten it to work in every browser, except Opera, where, as I add more items, the box gets bigger instead of staying the same size like in every other browser I've tested. (even IE!) Is there a way I can fix this? Here's the css:

```
float: left;
width: 854px;
height: 60px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
margin-top: 486px;
font-weight: 900;
```

Any advice?

Comment: do you have a fiddle or codepen where we can see it happen ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I don't think it'd work. I'm using the jquery playlist with jwplayer if that helps